# Yocto: closed source library with separated packages for library and header

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have my own .so closed source library and provide header file. My .so library file should be inside the yocto image, but header file should be used during another projects compilation only.

Here is yocto receipt:

```
SUMMARY = "foo library"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
SECTION = "libs"
SRC_URI = "file://usr/lib/libfoo.so \
           file://usr/include/foo.h "
S = "${WORKDIR}"
inherit autotools pkgconfig
do_compile() {
}
do_install() {
        install -d ${D}/usr/lib
        install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/usr/lib/libfoo.so ${D}/usr/lib/libfoo.so.1
        ln -s /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1 ${D}/usr/lib/libfoo.so
        install -d ${D}/usr/include
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/usr/include/foo.h ${D}/usr/include/
}

FILES_${PN}-dev += "${includedir} "
FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/libfoo.so \
        /usr/lib/libfoo.so.1"
PROVIDES += "libfoo"
```

I expect ${PN} package has libfoo.so and libfoo.so.1 and ${PN}-dev package has only one header file.  But yocto bitbake copies only libfoo.so.1 in ${PN} and libfoo.so is in ${PN}-dev packet.

Could you please help me how to move so file into ${PN} package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is correct here. Non-versioned .so files are installed in the -dev package because packages in the system should link against versioned files.

It is pretty uncommon to need to install a -dev package in an image, so effectively, only your versioned so file will make it.

As you saw already, the header is in the -dev package so won't make it to the image except if the -dev package is explicitly added to the image.

Because your header file is in `includedir` which is one of the directories used for the sysroot of other recipes (c.f. `SYSROOT_DIRS`), it'll be available to other recipes at build time. Same for your library as it's installed in `lib_dir` (also in aforementioned variable).

So the current behavior is expected. It is not clear why exactly you want your non-versioned symlink in the main package too.

If for some reason it's really what you want to do, you just need to add the following to your recipe:

```
 SOLIBS = ".so"
 FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
```

c.f. https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks/Packaging_Prebuilt_Libraries#Non-versioned_Libraries

Comment: Thanks for help @qschulz . We should support backward compatibility for projects which were linked against not versioned libraries before.